# subquery returns more than single value

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

i have 3 tables name REGISTERMASTER, FRIEND and UPLOAD.

i want to Get all the coloumn of UPLOAD `where UPLOAD.id= session["id"]` or its friendid and `REGISTERMASTER` having the details of all id so i want to get the details of those UPLOAD.id.

I write this Query

```
select * from upload left join registermaster on upload.id=registermaster.id where upload.id in ('"+Session["id"]+"', select userid from friend where frienid='"+Session["id"]+"' and approve='"+true+"')
```

but having the error that subquery returns more than one value

please help

Comment: How many rows are for this `(frienid,approve='True')` pair of values ? Max. one row; just one row; zero, one ore more rows ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `select top 1 userid from friend where frienid='"+Session["id"]+"' and approve='"+true+"')`